# Cassandra connection with anorm

Tags: cassandra, anorm

Is there a way to connect to Cassandra using anorm framework in scala.?

We are using Cassandra as primary DB and evaluating connection options our application needs. As part of that, I am checking the possibility to establish connectivity with Cassandra using anorm frame framework. I could not find any concrete examples yet.

Comment: Anorm is using JDBC to be DB agnostic, so a JDBC driver for Cassandra is required